# Elasticsearch Can I use "OR" or "AND" in the query_string phrase mode?

Tags: elasticsearch

e.g., I have two documents like "tasty apple is good" and "tasty banana is good".

Now I want to use the query_string to match the two phrases "tasty apple" and "tasty banana". In general, I can use query like

"\"tasty apple\" OR \"tasty banana\""

to match these documents.

But here I want the query like

"\"tasty (apple OR banana)\""

to match. It seems like the es doesn't support parentheses and bool in the phrase mode.

The reason why I need this above is as the number of the search word increasing, the valid query_string is more complicated.

For example when I want to search the

"\"(tasty OR nasty OR good) (apple OR banana OR grape)\""

I don't want to divide this query_string like

"\"tasty apple\" OR \"tasty banana\" OR \"tasty grape\" OR \"nasty apple\" OR ..."

Answer (score 2):

**Ingest documents**

```
POST test_david_zhao/_doc
{
  "text": "tasty apple is good"
}

POST test_david_zhao/_doc
{
  "text": "tasty grape is good"
}

POST test_david_zhao/_doc
{
  "text": "tasty banana is good"
}

POST test_david_zhao/_doc
{
  "text": "nasty banana is bad"
}

POST test_david_zhao/_doc
{
  "text": "dirty grape is bad"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_david_zhao/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text",
      "query": "+(text:apple text:banana text: grape) +(text:tasty text:nasty)"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.261763,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_david_zhao",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "d6t3_HcBDMyXCx985YKJ",
        "_score" : 2.261763,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "nasty banana is bad"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_david_zhao",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "dKt3_HcBDMyXCx9804Le",
        "_score" : 1.9252907,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "tasty apple is good"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_david_zhao",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "dat3_HcBDMyXCx982oIq",
        "_score" : 1.4144652,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "tasty grape is good"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_david_zhao",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "dqt3_HcBDMyXCx984IJD",
        "_score" : 1.4144652,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "tasty banana is good"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Here I want to use the phrase slop parameter in the query_string, so I need to use the phrase mode. It seems like this query cannot use slop to define the minimal distance between tasty and apple.